# what are the possible solutions to avoid page submit in angular in html5 mode

Tags: angularjs, routes

I am trying to submit a form in angular using ng-submit.
I got the html5 mode enabled and I am getting 404 error after submitting the form as it is reloading the whole page. I am using ngRoute for routing.

Thanks in advance for any suggestion

Comment: can you show your code?

Comment: <button  ng-click ="ctrl.submit()" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button> .it  posts the data but the url reloads to http://localhost:8085/HelloWorld/project/create .here is my angular js code.. :      self.createProject = function(){
    $http.post("project/create",self.project).then(function(response){
      self.message = response.data;
      self.reset();
     }, 
     function(errResponse){
      console.error('Error while creating user');
       $q.reject(errResponse);
     });
   };

Answer (score 0):

Why you bind click event on the submit button? You are saying you are using ng-submit. It should look like this:

```
<form (ngSubmit)="submit()" ...>
    <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

See the guide: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/NgForm-directive.html

Comment: sorry for the mismatch between  the title and the code commented as i  was trying with ng-click.basically i am  using angular 1.6 and using ng-submit in form .The data is posted  to the current url but the url reloads again .As  it is an angular router it's not able to find the same url  from server side. Any suggestion for url rewriting in java or in angualr will be very helpful for me to  use routing in html5  mode.thnx for ur response. hope u got the issue i am facing...

Comment: AngularJS is similar. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit